# Setting Up GLEW with VS2012

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to set up GLEW with Visual Studio 2012 and I'm having some trouble with it.

I downloaded the GLEW binary from http://glew.sourceforge.net/ and moved the contents from it's **lib** folder to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib** folder, and the contents from the **include\GL** folder to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\GL** folder.

Then I started up Visual Studio, and linked the glew32.lib in the linker properties section.

When I try to compile, I get the error: **error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew32.lib'**.

How can I get this to work, preferably without copying the libs to system32? (I'll do that if I really can't get this to work)

Answer (score 3):

After downloading the binary you can extract the whole folder anywhere. For this example lets say `C:\glew-1.9.0\`.

After doing so you can go in VS2012, right click on your project, go to `Configuration Properties`, `VC++ Directories`, select `Include Directories`, from the dropdown list select `<Edit...>`, click on `New Line (Ctrl+Insert)` and paste in `C:\glew-1.9.0\include`, then press `OK` and repeat same steps by selecting `Library Directories` and add `C:\glew-1.9.0\lib`.

After that you can simply use `#pragma comment(lib, "glew32")`.